# Authenticating with unencrypted POST credentials - is it safe?

Tags: tls, authentication, http

If a webpage is served over https and to authenticate it receives both login and password as unencrypted POST parameters (free text) is it considered unsafe?

Comment: Do you mean the POST goes over HTTPS (encrypted), or the POST goes over a different HTTP URL (not encrypted)?

Comment: the POST goes over HTTPS